# Computation of the first homology group of the sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am currently trying to compute the first homology group of the sphere, using the open tetrahedron (not solid).

Let $\gamma, \beta, \alpha, \rho, \delta, \nu$ represent the six edges (1-simplexes) making up the open tetrahedron.

Then $$C_1= < \gamma, \beta, \alpha, \rho, \delta, \nu>$$ the free abelian group generated by these edges.

Thus every arbitrary element in $C_1$ can  be represented as,

$a_1 \gamma + a_2 \beta + a_3 \alpha + a_4 \rho + a_5 \delta + a_6 \nu$ with $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then, $$im(d_1)= a_1 (b-a) + a_2 ( a-d) + a_3 (d-b) + a_4 (d-c) + a_5 ( c-a) + a_6 ( b-c)$$

I found the $ker(d_1)$ to be spanned by $a_1 + a_2 + a_3$, $a_2 + a_3 + a_5$, and $-a_2 - a_3 + a_6$.

I am not sure how to interpret this result. Is the above summation of the $a_i's$ a cycle? A video I watched interpreted it this way but I can't really make sense of it.

Comment: What do you mean by $\ker(d_1)$ spanned by some integers?

Comment: That is where I am confused. The $a_i's$ are just coefficients, but the video I watched interpreted them as cycles.

Comment: Anyway, I think in this case you can try to write down the chain complex and find out all its $d_i$, so that you can compute the simplicial homology explicitly......